# Why is it not possible to extract the Layers in a variable in ZIO Test

Tags: scala, zio, zio-test

When providing the Layers for my tests I stumbled over this strange behaviour, that it is not possible to extract the layers in a value.

This code compiles:

```
  def spec: ZSpec[environment.TestEnvironment, Any] =
    suite("EnvironmentLoaderSuites")(
        testM("the Config is correct") {
          assertM(environmentLoader.bpfEnv())(
            equalTo(expectedEnv))
        }
    ).provideCustomLayer(Console.live >>> loggings.consoleLogger >>> environmentLoader.live(testEnvPath))
```

When I now extract the layers like this:

```
  val layers = Console.live >>> loggings.consoleLogger >>> environmentLoader.live(testEnvPath)
  def spec: ZSpec[environment.TestEnvironment, Any] =
    suite("EnvironmentLoaderSuites")(
        testM("the Config is correct") {
          assertM(environmentLoader.bpfEnv())(
            equalTo(expectedEnv))
        }
    ).provideCustomLayer(layers)
```

I get the following compile exception:

```
Error:(48, 26) type mismatch;
 found   : zio.ZLayer[Any,Throwable,finnova.bpf.client.environmentLoader.EnvironmentLoader]
    (which expands to)  zio.ZLayer[Any,Throwable,zio.Has[finnova.bpf.client.environmentLoader.Service]]
 required: zio.ZLayer[zio.test.environment.TestEnvironment,zio.test.TestFailure[Any],?]
    (which expands to)  zio.ZLayer[zio.Has[zio.clock.Clock.Service] with zio.Has[zio.console.Console.Service] with zio.Has[zio.system.System.Service] with zio.Has[zio.random.Random.Service] with zio.Has[zio.blocking.Blocking.Service] with zio.Has[zio.test.Annotations.Service] with zio.Has[zio.test.environment.TestClock.Service] with zio.Has[zio.test.environment.TestConsole.Service] with zio.Has[zio.test.environment.Live.Service] with zio.Has[zio.test.environment.TestRandom.Service] with zio.Has[zio.test.Sized.Service] with zio.Has[zio.test.environment.TestSystem.Service],zio.test.TestFailure[Any],?]
    ).provideCustomLayer(layers)
```

Is this a restriction of ***ZIO Test*** or do I miss something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need to lift the failure type of your layer to a `TestFailure`. You can do this with `layer.mapError(TestFailure.fail)`. When you provided it directly the compiler may have widened the type since it was not fully known yet whereas now since you have defined an intermediate `val` the type is fully determined.